# Apache Web Server port 433 and Tomcat port 8080, redirect not working

Tags: apache, tomcat

My Apache web server runs on port `433` with `https` protocol. I wish to run Tomcat on port `8080` because there is no need for additional encryption, Tomcat is on the same machine, so I don't need port `8433`. But when I forward traffic from `433` to `8080` via `iptables` but I got an error: This site can’t provide a secure connection

```
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

What configurations do I need in tomcat `server.xml` and `apache.conf` in order to make this work?

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
<!-- I've tried this before when I thought I need an SSL for Tomcat. I think it's irrelevant now -->

<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                     certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                     certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

in `httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin root@localhost
     DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
     DirectoryIndex index.html
     ServerName mydomain.zone
     ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/mydomain.zone.error_log"
     CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/mydomain.zone.access_log" common
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.zone
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
Include /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf
```

EDIT: I've tried to delete iptables rule, and after that I added in httpd.conf:

```
ProxyPass / http://www.mydomain.zone:8080
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.mydomain.zone:8080
```

But I got the message: Service Unavailable The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later. (Tomcat is running I checked and Apache is restarted).

I've noticed that my web app works with normal HTTP protocol currently, but not with https, and I need to type`:8080`

Comment: Can you access Tomcat via `http://www.mydomain.zone:8080`? This is what Apache will try to do using your Proxy statements.

Comment: @f_puras yes, I can access it if I type it in URL

Comment: Well, standard way would be to proxy locally only: Get rid of your Rewrite rules and try changing the Proxy statements to `http://127.0.0.1:8080` This way you need not expose Tomcat externally.

Comment: @f_puras I've deleted `RewriteEngine`, `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`. I've edited proxy settings to `ProxyPass /`  `http://127.0.0.1:8080` and `ProxyPassReverse /`  `http://127.0.0.1:8080`. (I wrote it above the line `<VirtualHost *:80>`) It's still the same: I can access the app via http and I need to write `:8080`, but I can't via https (with or without `:8080`)

Comment: And I restarted Apache with `systemctl restart httpd`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot: You will need to add trailing slashes to the proxy targets, like here: https://serverfault.com/questions/287682

Comment: @f_puras I've tried with `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` and after restart still the same issue.

Comment: Are your Proxy statements part of the VirtualHost element? They need to be. If it still does not work, I am at my wits' end. Maybe still some dangling `iptable` rules present...?

Comment: @f_puras sorry, I didn't understand you where to write it. Now I moved it inside virtualhost.
Now I can open "Testing 123" Apache page with https (I couldn't before). But I can't reach my app with our without :8080 in my URL

Comment: @f_puras I wrote this in conf/httpd.conf. Maybe I should write it in conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf or in conf.d/ssl.conf?

Comment: It would not make a difference as long as the directives are included in any way from httpd.conf. I would expect site specific stuff in conf.d/, but it's up to your organizational scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 2 problems that occurred and the problem was not about proxy rules, I wrote them correctly.

I found the solution for the first problem here: http://sysadminsjourney.com/content/2010/02/01/apache-modproxy-error-13permission-denied-error-rhel/

Apparently, SELinux didn't allow httpd could not initiate outbound connections. I needed to allow it: `/usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`

The second problem was that my Tomcat used too much RAM memory because I configure SSL in `server.xml`, but SSL is already enabled in my Apache. When I commented that out, Tomcat reduced his RAM consumption.